# Error !Missing \endgroup inserted

Tags: tables

I'm trying to compile a table consisting of three r-tables from the semtable-package. unfortunately, I'm getting the *Error !Missing \endgroup inserted.\endgroup & multicolumn{4}{c}{A & N}*.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}r*{12}{S[
                         input-symbols = ( ) +,
                         group-digits = false,
                         table-number-alignment = center,
                         %table-space-text-pre = (,
                         table-align-text-pre = false,
                         table-align-text-post = false,
                         table-space-text-post = {***},
                         parse-units = false]}@{}}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{A & N}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{A, N & E}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{A, N & E & control}\tabularnewline \hline
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Estimate}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Err.}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{z}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{p}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Estimate}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Err.}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{z}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{p}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Estimate}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Err.}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{z}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{p}\tabularnewline\hline
& \multicolumn{9}{c}{\underline{Factor Loadings}}\tabularnewline \multicolumn{1}{l}{\underline{ABU}}\tabularnewline
NoSKMSM& 1.00$^+$& & & & 1.00$^+$& & & & 1.00$^+$& & & \tabularnewline
KSMChrMX& 0.71& 0.03& 22.62& .000& 0.73& 0.04& 20.38& .000& 0.73& 0.04& 19.89& .000\tabularnewline
KSMSevMx& 0.69& 0.03& 25.22& .000& 0.69& 0.03& 23.08& .000& 0.69& 0.03& 22.51& .000\tabularnewline
& \multicolumn{9}{c}{\underline{Fit Indices}}\tabularnewline
$\chi^{2}(\mathrm{df})$& 67.42& & & & 75.22& & & & 133.77& & & \tabularnewline
CFI& 0.99& & & & 1.00& & & & 1.00& & & \tabularnewline
RMSEA& 0.03& & & & 0.01& & & & 0.02& & & \tabularnewline
SRMR& 0.06& & & & 0.05& & & & 0.11& & & \tabularnewline
Scaled $\chi^{2}(\mathrm{df})$& 96.70(45)& & & .000& 135.52(71)& & & .000& 226.51(104)& & & .000\tabularnewline
\hline_BOML10_$^+$Fixed parameter}\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Welcometo TeX:SE! You have problems with `\multicolumn{4}{c}{A & N}` . What you like to get with ampersand in it? It can be there only as symbol `\&` or you need to eliminate it or close `multicoumn` cells before it, for example `\multicolumn{4}{c}{A} & N.

Comment: Beside mentioned problem, your table code has many other errors and it is not consistent regarding use of ampersands. Unclear is the last row, strange is `S` column specification, consequently table is wider than page etc.

Comment: Any news? We ask you to provide instead (now deleted) answer a new question regarding use of `longtable`. Do you solve this problem yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you looking for somethig like this:

[image]

As you can see, table is rotated, since it is to wide that can be fit on page in portrait orientation. I try to figured out your code, but I'm not sure if was lucky at all ambiguities and errors in your code. I also change page by use of the `geometry` package and table layout by use of rules from `booktabs` package instead of `\hline`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r *{3}{S[table-format=3.2(3),
                            table-space-text-post = $^{+}$,
                            table-align-text-post = false]
                          S[table-format=1.2]
                          S[table-format=2.2]
                          S[table-format=1.3]}
                @{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A \& N}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A, N \& E}
            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A, N \& E \& control}  \tabularnewline
    \cmidrule(l){2-5}
    \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    \cmidrule(l){10-13}
    & {Estimate}
        & {Std. Err.}
            & {z}
                & {p}
                    & {Estimate}
                        & {Std. Err.}
    & {z}
        & {p}
            & {Estimate}
                & {Std. Err.}
                    & {z}
                        & {p}                           \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Factor Loadings}}     \tabularnewline
%\multicolumn{1}{l}{\underline{ABU}}                     \tabularnewline
NoSKMSM
        & 1.00$^+$  & & & & 1.00$^+$ & & & & 1.00$^+$ & & & \tabularnewline
KSMChrMX
        & 0.71 & 0.03 & 22.62 & 0.000& 0.73 & 0.04 & 20.38 & .000 & 0.73 & 0.04 & 19.89& .000 \tabularnewline
KSMSevMx& 0.69& 0.03& 25.22& .000& 0.69& 0.03& 23.08& .000& 0.69& 0.03& 22.51& .000 \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Fit Indices}}         \tabularnewline
$\chi^{2}(\mathrm{df})$
        & 67.42 & & & & 75.22   & & & & 133.77  & & &   \tabularnewline
CFI     & 0.99  & & & & 1.00    & & & & 1.00    & & &   \tabularnewline
RMSEA   & 0.03  & & & & 0.01    & & & & 0.02    & & &   \tabularnewline
SRMR    & 0.06  & & & & 0.05    & & & & 0.11    & & &   \tabularnewline
Scaled $\chi^{2}(\mathrm{df})$
        & 96.70(45) & & & 0.000 & 135.52(71) & & & 0.000 & 226.51(104) & & & 0.000   \tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{13}{l}{BOML10$^+$Fixed parameter}
\end{tabular}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That did work, thanks for pointing out the missspecifiactions in my code. I was able to adjust my code according to your tips. However, I did shorten my example as the table is way longer. Now I have the problem that it is squeezed on one page. Would the right way to solve the problem include longtable?

Comment: @Jan, I know that my code work :-). Tell me, if suggested solution gives what you like to have? If it, than you may consider to accept my answer (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) ...